# autoResumeNumberOfSegments warning

Tags: chromecast

Recently we started receiving next warning:

```
[cast.framework.media.ShakaPlayer]
autoResumeNumberOfSegments is not supported for Shakaplayer.
Its value will be ignored
```

this caused regression in live stream loading time

Was this setting changed to something else?
How we can adjust buffering level now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it was never supported and documentation of playback config is wrong